# Logging in with Yii 2 - Comparing users password input to stored hash

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using `Yii 2` and I'm doing the login process now and I am aware you can use the [validatePassword](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-security.html#validatePassword()-detail) method to compare them, but this requires you to get the hash from the database.

Is there a way you can turn the users password input into a hash with the correct salt so you can compare the password with a database query such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password LIMIT 1
// other code
```

Comment: Just to make sure - Did you read the info on the Yii website that says the validatePassword() method is preferred because it relies on bcrypt? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-passwords.html

Comment: @robertgliguroski Well I am using it to create the passwords with bcrpyt.

Comment: Ok, I thought you weren't using it at all. Can you expand further on what exactly your problem is with the way it works("but this requires you to get the hash from the database.")?

Comment: @robertgliguroski I guess I'm just used to doing it that way - all in one shot rather than checking for the username and then getting the PW hash from that to compare. But not a big deal at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this part
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Security.php#L556
Password strategy is by default crypt
So you have this function `validatePassword($password, $hash)`

```
$test = crypt($password, $hash);
                $n = strlen($test);
                if ($n !== 60) {
                    return false;
                }
                return $this->compareString($test, $hash);
```

You should be able to get a hashed version of the password from here. I believe test would be the hashed version